# Free / Open source java shapes library?

Tags: java, graphics, shapes

I search for Java free open source shapes library,

That contains shapes like: Triangle, circle, Square, Polygon and etc'.

Of course it's should be graphics and not textual (terminal \ cmd).

Do you know about good one? Thank you.

Comment: What about [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html)?

Comment: Thanks that's what I looked for. but is there way to fill in some color these shapes?

Comment: Yes, over [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html)

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for something similar now. Have you found any good open-source libraries? I have posted my question here, can you please have look and provide some suggestions? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69885058/7584240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
That contains shapes like: Triangle, circle, Square, Polygon and etc'.
```

With exception to triangle, the Java Graphics API already contains all theses, and to be honest, triangle wouldn't be that hard to implement (it's a closed polygon with 3 points after all)

I'd start by reading through [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html), in particular [Working with Geometry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check out two particular ones (if you're still looking) the MyroJAVA program- this one is really designed for robots, but surprisingly has some pretty good Graphics library. http://wiki.roboteducation.org/Myro_in_Java

Also this library from Williams College: http://eventfuljava.cs.williams.edu/library.html